# chatbase: I need to recover the access to chatbase information (board) from my clients bots

Tags: chatbase

I need to recover the access to chatbase information (board) from my clients bots, because the responsible person left my company. How can I recover the access?

Best regards
Fábio

Answer (score 0):

Can you please email Chatbase-support@google.com with the name and api key of the bot as well as the email address of the former owner?

Comment: I tried it but I not received answer. I will try resent e-mail. Thanks